# Excel formula get value just greater than an other

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2016

I was wondering how to retrieve the smallest value greater than an other one.

To my knowns :

Using an approximate match,`VLOOKUP` searches for the value X in column A, finds the largest value less than or equal to X in column A.

What would be the equivalent of `VLOOKUP` in order to find the smallest value greater than or equal to x

Example : In this table if my value is -0,322

[image]

**`VLOOKUP`** returns : -0,362

Which Formula would return :-0,317 ?

Comment: Which version of excel do you have? If you have `Office365` then it is very easier to achieve.

Comment: @Harun24HR Excel2016

Comment: Approximate match works on sorted data. So it is getting `-0,362` greater than `-0,322` for second row as it is treating you data as sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use the following **array** formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A17>B1,A1:A17,""))
```

Where `B1` would be your the value to compare against.

Comment: Nice one ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

`Aggregate()` with `Index()` will help you then. Suppose you have `-0.322` in `C1` cell then use below formula. See screenshot for better understanding.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$1:$A$9)/($A$1:$A$9>$C$1),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

> ***Please Note:*** Comma (,) and dot (.) depends on regional settings. So just replace Dot (.) with comma for your excel.

Comment: What means 15 and 6 ?

Comment: thank you, your answer is working to ! I upvoted it

Comment: This non array formula, so no need to enter as `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`. Thanks for upvoting.